# How is the express module both a function/method AND an object with properties?

Tags: express

This may showcase my naivité, but I'm a little confused about how the express module can be used both like this:

```
*var app = express();*
```

**and** like this:

```
var router = express.Router();
```

How does that happen?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, a function can have properties.

Let's say we have:

```
function f() {
    console.log('f');
}
```

It's perfectly fine to have

```
f.someProperty = 'value';
```